# How to save value of TextField when a value is inputted in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have this code in a stateful class
The variables

```
String sth1 ;
String sth2 ;
```

I need these variables to each get a value from two TextFields once something is inputted. This is what I have

```
         TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              focusNode: f1,
              inputFormatters: [
                LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(1),
              ],
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              onChanged: (newVal) {
                if (newVal.length == 1) {
                    newVal = sth1;


                  f1.unfocus();
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(f2);
                }
```

Comment: That does not work. It says `newVal` is not defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `onChanged` should have `sth1 = newVal` not `newVal = sth1`.

Answer (score 3):

Take a

```
TextEditingController tec = new TextEditingController();
```

And pass it to the TextField as controller

```
TextField(controller: tec);
```

And when you want to get the text just use

```
tec.text;
```

Thats it!

Comment: And don't forget to call `tec.dispose()` in state's dispose function